# Can't paste files onto Android phone

Tags: usb, nautilus, android, mtp

OS – Ubuntu 16.04, 64-bit.

I just bought a Moto G4. I plug the USB cable into my computer, then I go to Apps > Play Music, and it says, "Copy music to your phone with a USB cable." Suddenly, my computer recognizes the Moto G4 as an external drive, and opens a Nautilus window for it.

However, there appears to be nothing in `/media/jps` ("jps" being my user name). [Screenshot.](https://s29.postimg.org/z0n9q8cxh/2017_02_04_01_00_52.png) Also, when I try to hover over the folder name in Nautilus, it just gives the file directory for the location as "`mtp://[usb:003,022]/`.

When I try to copy-paste some .mp3 files onto the device, the paste option is grayed out on the right-click context menu. It's as though it thinks there's nothing on my clipboard. And of course, I can't just use `cp` in the terminal, because the device directory above is not actually a real directory on my computer that the terminal can recognize.

What's going on?

Answer (score 3):

I touched the bar on the top of my smart phone screen, and it gave me the option of switching between USB modes – "charging", "file transfers (MTP)", "photo transfer (PTP)", and "MIDI". I switched from MTP to PTP, and suddenly I was able to paste files onto the device! So problem solved, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and in particular I wasn't able to paste files in the internal memory.

I solved in this way ( remember to set MTP mode )

- Go to “settings” and find “about device”
- Tap on build number few times until you see
  “Developer Mode Has Been Turned On”
- then go to “developer options”, make sure the **USB debugging** checkbox is ticked.

Now you should be able to copy files in the internal memory.

Answer (score 0):

Just open destination folder on phone and  source folder on your PC.then drag from PC folder and drop into phone folder and voila.that worked for me

Comment: Were you also unable to copy/paste using `cp` a CLI? In my experience, I've never been able to do something in the graphical interface that I was unable to do using the command that executes the same action.

Comment: This is not an answer, this is the expected behavior, and clearly the OP is having a problem with exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have SD card in my tablet and I was needed to copy files/folder from PC to tablet's internal memory. I was able to copy everything I needed just to root directory of my internal memory (Next to `Android`, `DCIM`, `documents` and other folders). Also I could create folders/sub-folders but could not copy anything to them. Root directory in my case was enough - then using internal Android file manager it was possible to cut/paste files/folder from root directory to anywhere else.

I could do it using MTP mode. Developer mode not required.