# Errors while copying stuff to android on Lubuntu

Tags: usb, 20.04, lubuntu, android, mtp

The android gets disconnected while moving files to my android device. It doesn't happens while copying files from windows partition, so it rules out the damaged USB port and I've tried many cables so the cables are also not damaged.

Once or twice I got something .lib... like error and because of it files weren't copying to the system. Unfortunately I don't have the errors name or the screenshot. (but at that time phone wasn't disconnecting again and again)

These are screenshots of current problem.

[Error Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM51Q.jpg)

[Error Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByZNs.jpg)

[Error Pic 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEbzZ.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't paste files onto Android phone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879677/cant-paste-files-onto-android-phone)